# Log-linear fit and parameters in case of perfectly correlated variables

Tags: r, log-linear

Here is an example case. Take the following ´data´:

```
> data <- data.frame('b' = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,1), c(2,5,3))),
+                    'c' = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,1), c(2,5,3)))
+ )
> data
   b c
1  1 1
2  1 1
3  2 2
4  2 2
5  2 2
6  2 2
7  2 2
8  1 1
9  1 1
10 1 1
```

Fitting a saturated loglin model results in the following fitted values and parameters:

```
> loglin(table = table(data), margin = list(c('c', 'b')), param = TRUE, fit = TRUE)
2 iterations: deviation 0 
$lrt
[1] 0

$pearson
[1] NaN

$df
[1] 0

$margin
$margin[[1]]
[1] "c" "b"


$fit
   c
b   1 2
  1 5 0
  2 0 5

$param
$param$`(Intercept)`
[1] -Inf

$param$b
  1   2 
NaN NaN 

$param$c
  1   2 
NaN NaN 

$param$b.c
   c
b     1   2
  1 NaN NaN
  2 NaN NaN
```

The fit is perfect, but the parameters are gibberish.

Anyone a clue what is wrong here? Is `loglin` using a different internal parametrization that allows to make good fit in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why `loglin` is doing that. It relies on passing data to a C function to get the model fit, and I think the error might be occurring there. The same model can be obtained using `glm` like:

```
require('magrittr')
require('tidyverse')
data <- data.frame('b' = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,1), c(2,5,3))),
                    'c' = as.factor(rep(c(1,2,1), c(2,5,3)))) %>% 
  count(b,c) %>% 
  complete(b,c, fill = list(n = 0))

glm(formula = n ~ b*c, data, family = poisson(link = "log"))

Call:  glm(formula = n ~ b * c, family = poisson(link = "log"), data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           b2           c2        b2:c2  
      1.609      -24.912      -24.912       49.824  

Degrees of Freedom: 3 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
Null Deviance:      13.86 
Residual Deviance: 0.0000000003033  AIC: 14.96
```